# Microsoft Graph API not respecting OData

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to pull all users within a specific group and to also get their transitive membership.

The endpoint I am hitting is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user?$select=givenName,surname,country,city,companyName,officeLocation,displayName,mail,department,jobTitle,employeeId&$expand=transitiveMemberOf
```

This pulls the data I need, but there is an object of OData type `microsoft.graph.group` in the returned payload that causes the following error:

```
A resource of type 'microsoft.graph.group' was found in a resource set that otherwise has entries of type 'microsoft.graph.user'. In OData, all entries in a resource set must have a common base type.
```

Which then causes a JSON parse error of `unexpected token`. The response does contain the next link and I would like to be able to handle this error and move on to the next page. However, the JSON::ParserError prevents me from doing this.

Any ideas what might cause a `microsoft.graph.group` object to be returned when `microsoft.graph.user` was specified in the request url?

Comment: Hello, would you share the request-id and date so we can look into this?

Comment: @Diana - Sure. I just ran it again now and the request id is `9b64e846-eade-4a2f-a7f6-f09efe316f32` and the timestamp is `2021-07-26T11:27:59`

Comment: Running into _exactly_ this as well! ->  `request-id: 158665a3-f8c0-464b-887c-ba7ba28c056d
client-request-id: 158665a3-f8c0-464b-887c-ba7ba28c056d
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","RoleInstance":"AM4PEPF0000DE26"}} Date: Fri, 03 Sep 2021 07:30:08 GMT`

Comment: @Diana Did you find anything for the given request ID? Could you check mine as well please?

Comment: I also reached out on Twitter as this really looks like a bug -> https://twitter.com/h_ulbricht/status/1433696705766117379?s=20 Maybe some of the Graph folks can chime in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to add the $count=true query parameter and setting the ConsistencyLevel header. This made the error go away and the call succeed.

It even says so in the documentation:

[image]

Whoops. Both the header and the query parameter are needed as of writing this.

Comment: Only seeing this now. I figured it out eventually with the same approach. Thanks Heinrich.