# MS Graph SDK: How to add URL segment to filter for specific member type?

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-sdks, group-membership

I'd like to get group members from Graph. No problem, the [API is there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). I now want to filter for members that are groups themselves and there even is a sample for this on the docs page:

[image]

See the `/microsoft.graph.group` part of the URL? That's what I want, but via Graph SDK.

Switching the sample to C# to see the corresponding code there is no evidence of this `microsoft.graph.group` URL part anymore:

[image]

Am I blind? How to apply this filter via Graph SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering is not supported by SDK code generator. As an alternative you can add segment to request url manually.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var requestUrl = graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"]
    .TransitiveMembers
    .AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("microsoft.graph.group?$count=true");

var group = await new GroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesRequest(requestUrl, graphClient, null)
    .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
    .GetAsync();
```

[Graph issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/MSGraph-SDK-Code-Generator/issues/239)

Comment: This seems to be the way and I'll accept it as answer. Thank you! Unfortunately I'm running into an issue when filtering for `microsoft.graph.user` that is already described over here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/68510538/56658

Comment: Oh well it seem you must also add the `$count=true` query parameter for the request to work - see the previously linked issue. Adding it to your answer.