# Microsoft Graph API is returning 200 ok with error response

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api

I am calling Microsoft graph API to get all the group names to which a specific user belongs. API is getting successfully called and returning 200 response code but response is giving internal server error along with response data.

```
End point : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$count=true

Response : 

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
  "value": [
   }{
      "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "A resource of type 'microsoft.graph.directoryRole' was found in a resource set that otherwise has entries of type 'microsoft.graph.group'. In OData, all entries in a resource set must have a common base type.",
        "innerError": {
          "date": "2021-09-06T07:18:07",
          "request-id": "3102e263-e4d8-49db-b7db-5f99a975d19c",
          "client-request-id": "3102e263-e4d8-49db-b7db-5f99a975d19c"
        }
      }
    }

Value array made blank as it is having clients data. But response is having proper details but it is appended with above "InnerError".
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

the solution posted here worked: [Microsoft Graph API not respecting OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68510538/microsoft-graph-api-not-respecting-odata/69069283#)

Reason is that Header Value is missing.

The original problem in that case is improper error Feedback when header values are missing.

Cheers